# How to solve lint error "Reference initialization causes loss of const/volatile integrity"

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, pc-lint

PC-lint is giving me the following error:

```
error 1561: (Warning -- Reference initialization causes loss of const/volatile integrity (arg. 'this'))
```

when processing the last line of this code:

```
auto sortedIter = std::find( _sortedSelectedItems.begin(), _sortedSelectedItems.end(), i );
if ( sortedIter != _sortedSelectedItems.end() )
            _sortedSelectedItems.erase(sortedIter); // here the lint issue appears
```

where `_sortedSelectedItems` is `std::vector<SmartPointer<DataItem>>`
Any idea why is this error appearing and how to fix it?

**edit**

This code is not inside a const member function.

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE)?

Comment: Try replacing `auto` with the actual type.

Comment: @dyp yes but I can't do that now as I don't have access to code, will have to do it tomorrow. But basically there is nothing extraordinary in this function. Just a normal member function of my class.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews sorry that I will have to wait for tomorrow to try your suggestion.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I replaced the auto with iterator once, and const_iterator the other and both times the lint error persisted. I talked with some of my experienced colleagues about this error today  and they said they can't find a good explanation why it occurs. Many of them said that they have just suppressed it because lint errors are not 100% accurate.

Comment: @dyp There is nothing extra-ordinary about the member function nor the class where this code is implemented. The member function is virtual, non-constant function. _sortedSelectedItems is a member variable of the type I described earlier in the question. DataItem is just a class type, you know what a smart pointer is, and we have a vector of that type. This code snippet is really all what you need to know if you want to trace the error reason. But if you have specific question I can answer them.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are modifying a class member whilst you are in a function marked with `const`.

Since you updated your post, we move on to the next question about your incomplete snippet: how is _sortedSelectedItems defined.

Comment: the function I am in is not const